# Python - debug HTML tag within a tag

Tags: python, html

I'm using Streamlit to highlight different keywords in text so I'm wrapping the keyword with
`<span style="background-color: #XXXXXX"> keyword </span>` but as some keywords are phrases I end having some text with a `<span>` within a `<span>` like

`<span style="background-color:FFFF000"> The quick brown fox <span style..>jumps</span> over the lazy dog </span>`

which results in **Error parsing Markdown or HTML in this string:**

I'm thinking to define a function to pass the string and remove the inner span in case is any

```
def html_debugger(text):
    magic
    return text
```

which would return `<span style="background-color:FFFF000"> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog </span>`
but I'm not sure how to think this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing it,

First with a standard library, [re](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html), it should work with any kind of tag, not only `span`:

```py
import re

html = """<span style="background-color:FFFF000"> The quick brown fox <span style="test">jumps</span> over the lazy dog </span>"""

def html_debugger(text):
    tag_pattern = r'<[^>]*>'
    tags = re.findall(tag_pattern, text)
    inside_text = re.sub(tag_pattern, '', text)
    
    return tags[0] + inside_text + tags[-1]

html_debugger(html)
# '<span style="background-color:FFFF000"> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog </span>'
```

Second with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span style="background-color:FFFF000"> The quick brown fox <span style="test">jumps</span> over the lazy dog </span>"""

def html_debugger(text):
    bs_span = BeautifulSoup(text)
    span = s.find_all('span')[0]
    
    span_text = span.text
    span_style = span.attrs['style']
    
    return f'<span style="{span_style}">{span_text}</span>'

html_debugger(html)
# '<span style="background-color:FFFF000"> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog </span>'
```

Comment: the second one is very clever, I missed to clarify that I usually have large texts which have several <span> over the text, but not all of them are within each other. With your solution I think I can come with something to solve the ones that are causing problem :). I'm thinking to loop through them and check if they contain a <span> within